# how to filter record use date only in rails & postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have some data like

```
id   post  created_at
1     test  timestamp 
2     hello  timestamp 
3     test  timestamp
```

- how can return data for specific date for example `2020-06-14`
- how can return data for specific hour from  specific date `2020-06-14 11`

i  use rails, postgres

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Post.where("date(created_at) = ?", Date.parse('2020-06-14'))
```

and

```
Post.where("date_trunc('hour', created_at) = ?", Time.parse('2020-06-14 11:00'))
```